# How to view error console?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, error, log

How do you view the error console I keep hearing mentioned? I passed --contracts-console in my initial set up (i'm using the docker image) but no console runs in the background or opens when I call to cleos etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `--contracts-console` option to `nodeos` will cause it to output any print statements made by a smart contract to its console log.  When running from the command line, these end up in the terminal.  If running from Docker, check the nodeos log file.